# Combobox with LimitToList set to false with non-bound field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a `products` table and a `tags` table with a many-to-many relationship. I also have a pivot table that store the product id and the tag id.

I'd like to be able to show the tag text in the combo box but store the id. This on its own is simple as I can just adjust the column width of the id, however, I'm trying to set `LimitToList` to `No` so I can implement some VBA to filter the list when I type in the combo box, but this only appears to be possible if the first column is the bound column, which means the tag id appears in the combo box instead of the text.

How do I show the tag text in the combobox and allow 'LimitToList' to be false?

Answer (score 0):

Leave `LimitToList` on `Yes`, and use the **`NotInList`** event of the combobox instead.
E.g.

```vb
Private Sub cboTag_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)

    Dim RS As Recordset

    If MsgBox("Do you want to add '" & NewData & "' as new Tag?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) _ 
       = vbYes Then
        ' Add the new tag
        Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbTags")
        With RS
            .AddNew
            !Tag_Text = NewData
            .Update
            .Close
        End With
        Response = acDataErrAdded
    Else
        Response = acDataErrDisplay
        ' Or a user defined MsgBox and acDataErrContinue
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This wouldn't work surely, becuase if I started to type 'q' for 'qwerty', it'd ask me if I wanted to add 'q' to the list? Would I be able to update the rowsource query in this event with a `where tag like '*" & txtBox.Text & "*'? Would that recursively trigger the event or would it allow another character to be typed?

Comment: You should simply try it. :) The `NotInList` event is triggered when you have entered text into the field, and want to leave it. Just like `AfterUpdate`.

Answer (score 0):

(sigh) again I have misunderstood your question. :(

To **filter** the combobox as the user types a part of a Tag, you use the `Change` event. This works just fine with `LimitToList = Yes`.

```vb
Private Sub cboTag_Change()

    Me.cboTag.RowSource = _
       "SELECT Tag_ID, Tag_Text FROM tbTags WHERE Tag_Text LIKE '*" & Me.cboTag.Text & "*'"

    ' With the instant filtering, it is more convenient for the user 
    ' to always see the filtered dropdown
    Me.cboTag.Dropdown

End Sub
```

Of course at some point the user has to select a Tag from the list. Otherwise there would be no ID to store in the field.
Or if you want him to be able to add new tags, use the code from the other answer. Both events work together as written.

Answer (score 0):

Search-as-you type technique described very good [here](http://e-e.com/A_6490.html), including automatic selection of items from opened dropdown combobox after typing few characters.